# cf9 orm entityload in random order

Tags: orm, coldfusion

How would I do an entityload with its resultset being in random order?

So if I do `entityload("modelName")`, how Would set it's sort order so that it is randomly different each time I call it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the short answer is it is really difficult with entityLoad(). However, with HQL, it's actually not too bad.

Most DB languages will have a random function. So, using the built in art table and an entity, you can use ormExecuteQuery to generate your results:

```
<cfscript>
hql = " SELECT DISTINCT artName
        FROM art
        ORDER BY RANDOM() ";

results = ormExecuteQuery(hql);

for( art in results ) {
    writeOutput(art & "<br/>");
}
</cfscript>
```

Because it won't return any null records, you will get a random result set every time.

Hope this helps ^__^

Comment: Good answer. As you say the function will depend on your DB. In MySQL it's RAND() rather than RANDOM()

Comment: Thanks jcaito.. that worked a treat.. only problem was that I didn't get my setters and getters back.. data just came back as an array or arrays(?).  I also used another approach which gave me a full entity back, including all getters and setters, will post as an alternative answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I used is to create a sortOrder column in my table (and model) and a function to randomly populate it.  probably not as efficient as jCaito's option, but had some benefits.

```
public function getRandom(){
    randomizer();
    return entityload("provider", {}, "sortOrder");
}

private void function randomizer(){
    source = entityload("provider");
    for(i=1;i<=ArrayLen(source);i++){        
        source[i].setSortOrder(randRange(1,999));        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd maybe suggest changing your range to being `randRange( 1, source.len() )`, that way it will sort within the array's length